# How to search an array of objects in mongoDB without using aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a use case where the data is stored in the below format

```
[
  {
    "Name": [
      {
        "KM": "2"
      },
      {
        "Weld Joint Number": "JN2"
      },
      {
        "Status": "Accepted"
      },
      {
        "Upstream": "PP1"
      },
      {
        "Downstream": "PP2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": [
      {
        "Pipe No": "PP5731A-08"
      },
      {
        "Km": "1"
      },
      {
        "Section Length (m)": "12.22"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

We are checking for the possibility where we need to search the records using the find query(without aggregate) which matches the search criteria for the values in that array of Objects.
In the search scenario, the value can match with any value in the array.

Comment: why you dont want to use aggregate? if you can give an example of what you need, and the expected output in json, also if you have many different keys, maybe you can use `{"type" : "status" , "value" : "Accepted"}` so the schema to be similar inside the array

Comment: Are you showing a sample _collection_ or an array that appears in a _document_?

Comment: Aggregate seems like the right tool for the job here. But +1 on the previous clarification question

Comment: Hey, @rickhg12hs We are showing only an array in a document, not a collection.

Comment: @Takis, we are using the mongoose paginate(with find query) which is providing us to use the pagination concept by default.
Ex : 
`var options = { limit: 20, page: 1 }
            collection.paginate(matchQuery, options)`

If we use aggregate we need to specify the Skip and Limit pipelines explicitly to use the pagination concept, which might have a performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to `find` documents with a given single value in an object nested in arrays.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$in": [
      // search value goes here
      "Accepted",
      { // this puts all the values into a flat array
        "$reduce": {
          // instead of "stuff", use the field name of the array
          "input": "$stuff.Name",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$this",
                  "as": "elem",
                  "in": {
                    "$getField": {
                      "field": "v",
                      "input": {"$first": {"$objectToArray": "$$elem"}}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W7B2G2s_sYL).